# Timer class with delegates C#

Tags: c#, .net

I need to implement the `Timer` class for simulating a countdown clock. The Timer has the ability to send out messages with the information about  `Started`, `Tick` and `Stopped` events to other types subscribed to the events. I can't use the .NET System.Timer classes for this implementation.
The `Timer` class should have the following functionality:
- When an object of the `Timer` class is constructed it has to be assigned:
- Name (not a null or an empty string, otherwise the exception `ArgumentException` should be thrown);
- Number of ticks (the number has to be greater than 0; otherwise, the exception  `ArgumentException` should be thrown).
- After  the Timer has been created it should be called to Run. In response to Run, the Timer fires the `Started` event. The event should contain the information about the Timer's Name and the Number of ticks to be fired.
- After firing the `Started` event, the Timer starts firing `Tick` events with the information abount the Timer's name and the number of ticks left to fire.  There should be delays between the `Tick` events. To emulate the delays between the `Tick` events, it is recommended to use the `Thread.Sleep` method.
- After all `Tick` events have been fired, the Timer has to fire `Stopped` event, the event should contain the Timer's name information.

```
public class Timer
{
    private string name;
    private int numberOfTicks;

    public Timer(string name, int numberOfTicks)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.NumberOfTicks = numberOfTicks;
    }

    public event Action<string, int> Tick;

    public event Action<string> Ticks;

    public void OnStarted(Action<string, int> startDelegate)
    {
        this.Tick = startDelegate;
        startDelegate?.Invoke(this.Name, this.NumberOfTicks);
    }

    public void OnStopped(Action<string> stopDelegate)
    {
        this.Ticks = stopDelegate;
        stopDelegate?.Invoke(this.Name);
    }

    public void OnTick(Action<string, int> tickDelegate)
    {
        this.Tick = tickDelegate;
        tickDelegate?.Invoke(this.Name, this.NumberOfTicks - 1);
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => this.name;

        set
        {
            this.name = value;
            if (value == null || value.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Name is empty or null.", nameof(this.Name));
            }
        }
    }

    public int NumberOfTicks
    {
        get => this.numberOfTicks;
        set
        {
            this.numberOfTicks = value;
            if (value <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Number of ticks is less than zero.", nameof(this.NumberOfTicks));
            }
        }
    }
}



public class TimerFactory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create an object of the <see cref="Timer"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">Name of timer.</param>
    /// <param name="ticks">Count of ticks.</param>
    /// <returns>A reference to an object of the <see cref="Timer"/> class.</returns>
    public Timer CreateTimer(string name, int ticks)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(name, ticks);
        return timer;
    }
}

public class CountDownNotifier : ICountDownNotifier
{
    private Timer timer;

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public void Init(Action<string, int> startDelegate, Action<string> stopDelegate, Action<string, int> tickDelegate)
    {
        this.timer.OnStarted(startDelegate);
        this.timer.OnStopped(stopDelegate);
        this.timer.OnTick(tickDelegate);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public void Run()
    {
    }
}

public class CountDownNotifierFactory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create an object of the class that implements the <see cref="ICountDownNotifier"/> interface.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="timer">A reference to a class CustomTimer.</param>
    /// <returns>A reference to an object of the class that implements the <see cref="ICountDownNotifier"/> interface.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">When timer is null.</exception>
    public ICountDownNotifier CreateNotifierForTimer(Timer timer)
    {
        if (timer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(timer));
        }

    }
}
```

I have a problem with this task. I don't know how to correct it. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Related: [Problem with receiving suitable value with action event in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72116725/problem-with-receiving-suitable-value-with-action-event-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I suggest that you read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html) and follow the standard conventions for events. If you do it how it's intended to be done, you won't have to solve problems that you created for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I created small `Timer` class for you. I did not handle exceptions and other things, you will do it. I implemented multiple ways of creating timer.

To use timer you write:

```
Timer timer = new Timer("Some Name", 100, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
timer.Started += OnTimerStarted;
timer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
timer.Stopped += OnTimerStopped;
timer.Start();

private void OnTimerStarted()
{
}
private void OnTimerTick()
{
}
private void OnTimerStopped()
{
}
```

or

```
Timer timer = new Timer("Some Name", 100, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), OnTimerStarted, OnTimerTick, OnTimerStopped); // This one will start timer immediately
```

or

```
Timer timer = Timer.Run("Some Name", 100, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), OnTimerStarted, OnTimerTick, OnTimerStopped); // This one will start timer immediately
```

```
public class Timer
{
    #region Delegtes Definition
    public delegate void OnStarted();
    public delegate void OnTick();
    public delegate void OnStopped();
    #endregion

    #region Delegates
    public OnStarted? Started { get; set; }
    public OnTick? Tick { get; set; }
    public OnStopped? Stopped { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    private string _name { get; set; }
    private int _nTicks { get; set; }
    private TimeSpan _tickTimeout { get; set; }
    private DateTime _lastTick { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    private bool __forceStop { get; set; } = false;
    private bool _forceStop
    {
        get
        {
            return __forceStop;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == true)
                if (Stopped != null)
                    Stopped();

            __forceStop = true;
        }
    }
    private bool _started { get; set; } = false;
    public string Name { get { return _name; } }
    public int NumberOfTicks { get { return _nTicks; } }
    public TimeSpan TickTimeout { get { return _tickTimeout;} }
    #endregion

    public Timer(string name, int numberOfTicks, TimeSpan tickTimeout)
    {
        _name = name;
        _nTicks = numberOfTicks;
        _tickTimeout = tickTimeout;
    }
    public Timer(string name, int numberOfTicks, TimeSpan tickTimeout, OnStarted startedHandler, OnTick tickHandler, OnStopped stopHanlder, bool autoStart = true)
    {
        _name = name;
        _nTicks = numberOfTicks;
        _tickTimeout = tickTimeout;
        Started += startedHandler;
        Tick += tickHandler;
        Stopped += stopHanlder;

        if (autoStart)
            Start();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (_started)
            throw new Exception("Already started!");

        _started = true;

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Running this delegate on separate thread so I do not stop tick for code inside to execute
            if (Started != null)
                Started();
        });

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            _lastTick = DateTime.Now;
            while (!_forceStop)
            {
                while (_lastTick.Add(_tickTimeout) > DateTime.Now)
                {
                    if (_forceStop)
                        return;

                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                }

                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    // Running this delegate on separate thread so I do not stop tick for code inside to execute
                    if (Tick != null)
                        Tick();

                });
                _lastTick = DateTime.Now;
            }
        });
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        _forceStop = true;
    }
    public Timer Run(string name, int numberOfTicks, TimeSpan tickTimeout, OnStarted startedHandler, OnTick tickHandler, OnStopped stopHanlder)
    {
        return new Timer(name, numberOfTicks, tickTimeout, startedHandler, tickHandler, stopHanlder);
    }
}
```